# How to send option value (instead of the html text inside) of select option dropdown via ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating a page that needs to send post data using Ajax (JQuery).

The (most relevant) HTML code is the following:

```
<div class="command-list">
  <form action="app_page.php" method="post">
    <select name="TYPE" class="form-control">
      <option vaule="VALUE 1">DISPLAYED TEXT 1</option>
      <option vaule="VALUE 2">DISPLAYED TEXT 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" class="ibtnSave" value="Salvar">
  </form>
</div>
```

The JQuery function that is being used to send the form data is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".command-list").on("click", ".ibtnSave", function (event) {
        var tosave = $(this).closest("form"); // Gets the form that the button belongs to
        var r = $.post('app_page.php', tosave.serialize()); // Sends the form data via POST to my application page
});
```

On the server-side (PHP application), when the POST data is retreived, the values received are either 'DISPLAYED TEXT 1' or 'DISPLAYED TEXT 2' instead of 'VALUE 1' or 'VALUE 2' as expected in a normal form sent via html.

How can I send only the data inside value attribute instead of the text displayed between the option tags?

Summarizing:

Current data being sent: TYPE=DISPLAYED TEXT 1

What I really want to send: TYPE=VALUE 1

**EDIT**

Status: Problem Solved

I've misspelled 'value' attribute on my HTML code.
On the code above, it says 'vaule' instead of 'value'.

Thanks.

Comment: _"What I really want to send: TYPE=VALUE 1"_ `TYPE=VALUE 1` should be submitted to server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
<option vaule="VALUE 1">DISPLAYED TEXT 1</option>
        ^^^ should be value
```

If an option has no value (in your case due to the typo), the displayed text is used instead.

Comment: a simple answer, to a mind-bending "strange" behavior I've been trying to solve for days.  Thank you!